# css attribute selector not matching dynamically added class names

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am using react's CSS animations add-on and everything works fine when I use their provided classnames.

```
.quote-enter {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in;
}

.quote-enter.quote-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.quote-leave {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in;
}

.quote-leave.quote-leave-active {
  opacity: 0.01;
}
```

but when I try to convert that to an attribute selector method to catch each instance of component that should animate, it doesn't work, no selector matches.

```
[class$='-enter'] {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in;
}

[class$='-enter'][class$='-enter-active'] {
  opacity: 1;
}

[class$='-leave'] {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in;
}

[class$='-leave'][class$='-leave-active'] {
  opacity: 0.01;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$=` operator matches the end of the whole attribute, so if the class you're targeting isn't the last one of the element (say `class="whatever-enter other-class"`), the selector won't match.

You can try this:

```
[class$='-enter'], [class*='-enter '] {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in;
}
[class$='-leave'], [class*='-leave '] {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in;
}
```

It will become more complex when combining two classes (2*2 = 4 selectors), so maybe you'll be better off sticking to the `*=`operator alone:

```
[class*='-enter'] {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in;
}

[class*='-enter'][class*='-enter-active'] {
  opacity: 1;
}

[class*='-leave'] {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in;
}

[class*='-leave'][class*='-leave-active'] {
  opacity: 0.01;
}
```

This will work as long as you don't have any other classes ending with these suffixes.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Wouldn't [class*='-leave'][class*='-leave-active']  theoretically be a double match? Maybe I can just omit the first selector with the wild card and just force css ordering - as in, *-enter will be overridden by -enter-active so long as it follows.

Comment: checked it, it works. Also works with my theoretical '-leave' before '-leave-active' - thanks! The point, sir, is to you.

Comment: Yes, you're right, `[class*='-leave'][class*='-leave-active']` is redundant and can be replaced by `[class*='-leave-active']` alone.